# Does resetting table ids impact any performance?

Tags: identifier

When you have a high number of ids, but they aren't used anymore. Should you reset the id of the table? And does it have any performance difference?

Comment: What do you mean? What is "reset"? Remove column? alter values to least and adjacent? something else? *does it have any performance difference?* If you do not change its datatype - no, of course.

Comment: which database ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It's probably not worth the effort.

If you mean that your auto-incremented values are "very high" and you are considering resetting the auto-increment value back to, say, zero, then *maybe*.

The most important consideration is that you don't *run out* of or attempt to *duplicate* values.
As to the numerical value of each one?  Doesn't matter a jot.  Whilst, to you or me, the Integer value **4,294,967,293** "looks" bigger than **12**, the DBMS sees them *exactly the same* - four bytes of Data with "stuff" in them.
The risk you run by resetting the auto-increment value is that if you were to get a rush of new records being added, you might "catch-up" with the older records with larger id's - and then your application would start breaking all over the place.

Alternatively, if you mean that all your records id's are "very high" and you want to *re-map* them all to smaller values?
**Do not do this**.
Here's an analogy as to why not.  A bunch of people close their accounts at your bank.  Would you expect your checking account number to be "resequenced" to some smaller value as a result?  Of course not.  There would be [historical] confusion about who had which account number at which point in time and the chances of things (i.e. money!) "crossing-over" into the wrong accounts during the switchover(s)?  Not worth thinking about.

Changing primary (and, of course, *foreign*) key values in a database is *this* scale of operation - not to be done lightly, or even at all.